# How to have the four quarter of Year relative to a date

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working on java swing application with hibernate .
I want to show on jasperreport results for each quarter of a year (I have in database dates so I will extract years that correspond to these dates that I have on my database) I find some solutions but I think that's not really a good one ,that's the easy way:

```
select * from dbcheques.Cheque
where YEAR(dateEncaissement) = '2013'
and (MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 7
or MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 8 or MONTH(dateEncaissement) >= 9)
```

that will return the third quarter of that year , nearly the same query for other quarter only the number change:

**For the first quarter**

```
and (MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 1 or MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 2
or MONTH(dateEncaissement) >= 3)
```

**For the second quarter**

```
and (MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 4 or MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 5
or MONTH(dateEncaissement) >= 6)
```

**For the last quarter**

```
and (MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 10 or MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 11
or MONTH(dateEncaissement) = 12)
```

this is the interface:

!(http://hpics.li/7ca6010)

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Does your DB support 'Between' in the where clause? You use it instead if that's the case.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: some query or some method that can get the four quarter of a selected year and as I said that year is extracted from dates on my database, that result will be shown on a report.

Comment: i'm using mysql it supports between and where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "how to get the values for a given quarter (1, 2, 3 or 4)", then you can simply use

```
where ((MONTH(dateEncaissement) - 1) DIV 3) + 1 = <quarter>
```

If you want to select rows from the table, including the quarter of each row, then use the same trick in the select clause:

```
select *, (((MONTH(dateEncaissement) - 1) DIV 3) + 1) as quarter from ...
```

Comment: Thanks @JN Nizet this is exactly what I want , I will just add the clause where dateEncaissement = (the Year selected) but that's not really working , it gives the exactly quarter but with decimal like that '1.6667' or '3.333' so when i do  that where ((MONTH(dateEncaissement) - 1) / 3) + 1 = 1 ... that's not working

Comment: That's because MySQL's integer division is DIV, and not /. On postreSQL, it works as is. Replace / with DIV, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

To query for current quarter:

```java
String sql = 
 "SELECT … 
  FROM … 
  WHERE 
    dateCol_ >= ? 
    AND
    dateCol_ < ?
  ;"

YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , yq.atDay( 1 );
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , yq.plusQuarters(1).atDay( 1 );
```

## java.time

The [Answer by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432543/642706) is correct.

Another option is determining the dates within Java using the java.time classes and their extension, the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. That project adds the classes [`Quarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html) and [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html).

### `YearQuarter`

Determining a quarter means determining a date. Determining a date means specifying a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.now( z );
```

You can do math, adding and subtracting.

```
YearQuarter yqNext = yq.plusQuarters( 1 );
```

### `LocalDate`

You can interrogate for the first and last dates of that quarter, to get `LocalDate` objects. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate firstDay = yq.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate lastDay = yq.atEndOfQuarter();
```

Usually better in date-time work to use the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time as the beginning being *inclusive* and the ending being *exclusive*. This approach is used in the query seen at the top of this Answer.

```
LocalDate startOfNextQuarter = yq.plusQuarters( 1 ).atDay( 1 );
```

## Database

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 and later, you may be able to pass the `LocalDate` object via the `PreparedStatement` object’s `setObject` method.

If not, fall back to using the [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class. New methods added to the old classes facilitate conversion.

```
java.sql.Date d = java.sql.Date.valueOf( firstDay );
```